# How to add delay in nodejs

Tags: node.js

i am calling a 3rd party API in a loop in my nodejs application. Basically I have a list, am iterating through the list and calling the 3rd party API. 
The 3rd party API is very slow and cannot handle more than 3 requests. I have been advised to add some delay.
Please can someone advise how to add delay in this scenario.

```
    var promises = [];
    promises = rids.map((rid,j) => {
        // 3rd party API
        // getServiceDetailsApi is wrapper around 3rd party API
        return getServiceDetailsApi(rid)
    });
    // console.log(promises);
    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(res => {
        // console.log('promise complete..' + res.length)

        var responses = [];
        res.map((response,i) => {
            var serviceAttributesDetail = {};
            // console.log(response);
            serviceAttributesDetails = response.data.serviceAttributesDetails;
            serviceAttributesDetail.rid = serviceAttributesDetails.rid;
            responses = responses.concat(serviceAttributesDetail);
        })
        // Add more logic above
        return Promise.all(responses); 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If one request at a time is enough, you can try this way:

```js
'use strict';

(async function main() {
  try {
    const responses = [];
    for (const rid of rids) {
      const response = await getServiceDetailsApi(rid);
      responses.push({ rid: response.data.serviceAttributesDetails.rid });
    }
    console.log(responses);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your restriction is about having a maximum of 3 concurrent requests to that API, here is a possibility (untested though, there might be typos, and I didn't think the rejection handling):

```
const cfgMaxApiCalls = 3;
...
function getServiceDetailsApi() {...}
...
const rids = ...
...
const promisedResponses = new Promise((generalResolve) => {
  let currentCalls = 0; // to know how many calls in progress
  const responses = []; // the output of the general promise
  // this chains promises, ensuring we do an API call only when another one finished
  const consumer = (response) => {
    responses.push(response); // first remember the data
    // stop condition: nothing more to process, and all current calls have resolved
    if (!rids.length && !currentCalls--) {
      return generalResolve(responses);
    }
    // otherwise make a new call since this one's done
    return getServiceDetailsApi(rids.shift()).then(consumer);
  };
  // start the process for maximum `cfgMaxApiCalls` concurrent calls
  for (; currentCalls < cfgMaxApiCalls && rids.length; currentCalls++) {
    getServiceDetailsApi(rids.shift()).then(consumer);
  }
});
promisedResponses.then((res) => {
  // here `res` === your code's `res`
  // and by the way, Array.prototype.concat is not asynchronous,
  // so no need to Promise.all(responses) at the end ;)
});
```